# Error on setMapping for managed property

Tags: development, managed-metadata, user-profile-property

I'm getting error when i try to add a crawled property to managed property "contentshidden"

Anyone know why the problem can ben, when i add a mapping to empty mapping property it is ok, but when i add to contentshidden then i get an error:

```
 IList<CrawledProperty> crawledProperties = new List<CrawledProperty>();
            Schema schema = new Schema(searchServiceApplication);
            ManagedPropertyCollection allManagedPropertiesCollection = schema.AllManagedProperties;

            foreach (Property p in propertiesList)
            {
                foreach (CrawledProperty crawledProperty in schema.QueryCrawledProperties(string.Empty, 1000, Guid.NewGuid(), string.Empty, true))
                {
                    if (crawledProperty.Name.Contains(p.Name) && !allManagedPropertiesCollection.Contains(p.Name))
                    {
                        string name = crawledProperty.Name;
                        if (!crawledProperty.Name.Contains("ows"))
                        {
                            crawledProperties.Add(crawledProperty);
                            ManagedProperty managedProperty = allManagedPropertiesCollection.Create(p.Name, ManagedDataType.Text);
                            ManagedProperty hiddenContentManagedProperty = allManagedPropertiesCollection["ContentsHidden"];

                            Mapping mapping = new Mapping(crawledProperty.Propset, crawledProperty.Name, crawledProperty.VariantType, managedProperty.PID);

                            MappingCollection mappingCollection = managedProperty.GetMappings();
                            MappingCollection hiddenContentsMappingCollection = hiddenContentManagedProperty.GetMappings();
                            if (!mappingCollection.Contains(mapping))
                            {
                                mappingCollection.Add(mapping);
                                managedProperty.SetMappings(mappingCollection);
                                managedProperty.Update();
                            }
                            if (!hiddenContentsMappingCollection.Contains(mapping))
                            {
                                hiddenContentsMappingCollection.Add(mapping);

                                hiddenContentManagedProperty.SetMappings(hiddenContentsMappingCollection);
                                hiddenContentManagedProperty.Update();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

UPDATE:
The error that im getting: "The mapping must be to the managed property being set."

Thanks in advance

Comment: You get an exception? Post the exception :-)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this line is the root cause:

```
hiddenContentsMappingCollection.Add(mapping);
```

You are trying to add a mapping created for one managed property to another managed property. `mapping` was created for `managedProperty` and not `hiddenContentManagedProperty` (see the last parameter):

```
Mapping mapping = new Mapping(crawledProperty.Propset, crawledProperty.Name, crawledProperty.VariantType, managedProperty.PID);
```

The solution would be to create a second mapping like this:

```
Mapping hiddenContentsMapping = new Mapping(crawledProperty.Propset, crawledProperty.Name, crawledProperty.VariantType, hiddenContentManagedProperty.PID);
```

Then you would add this mapping to the `hiddenContentsMappingCollection`:

```
hiddenContentsMappingCollection.Add(hiddenContentsMapping );
```